# kotlin regex pattern for valid amount

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to restrict Field to take only valid amounts, I have already enabled the number keyboard but It contains some symbols like - (- , SPACE)

Example Valid Amount: 200, 200.00

Comment: whats the valid amount ? add few Example with question .. Integer, decimal .

Comment: It should accept both Integer as well as Decimal, But should not accept value with space or other character or symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to check if input can be parse as `Double`.. Somthing like this ->

```
@Composable
fun AmountTextField(
text: String,
onChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
TextField(value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches("[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?".toRegex())) onChanged(it)
    },
    keyboardOptions =
    KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal)
)
}
```

Alternatively you can also use [toDoubleOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) .

```
@Composable
fun AmountTextField(
text: String,
onChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
TextField(value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.toDoubleOrNull()!=null) onChanged(it)
    },
    keyboardOptions =
    KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal)
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood that correctly, you should use `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$` so that you can do [some numbers without separation] and a dot plus some more numbers without separation, both of the latter as optionals.